# Join MINT 20 System to Windows Server 2003 AD fails with "failed to lookup DC: Device Timeout

Tags: networking, samba, active-directory

I've been following the instructions provided in https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_Samba_as_a_Domain_Member to try and get a Mint Linux 20 machine added to my Windows Server 2003 domain. At the point where I'm supposed to join the domain, it fails with the error message above. This is not quite a repost of an earlier question; before, I was trying to use the unsupported sssd mechanism, now I'm using winbind, and it's failing the same way.

Here are the config files - I've edited them so that the domain I'm using is now called $domain_name$ (and yes, it is .local, dating back to about 2000 and machines where you could not edit the domain name once it was created, and it does have an underscore in it); and the AD server is named $adserver$. I've retained capitalization, of course.

/etc/krb5.conf:

```
[libdefaults]
        default_realm = $DOMAIN_NAME$.LOCAL
        kdc_timesync = 1
        ccache_type = 4
        forwardable = true
        proxiable = true
        dns_lookup_realm = false
        dns_lookup_kdc = true
        renew_lifetime = 7d
        default_tgs_enctypes = rc4-hmac des-cbc-crc des-cbc-md5
        default_tkt_enctypes = rc4-hmac des-cbc-crc des-cbc-md5
        permitted_enctypes = rc4-hmac des-cbc-crc des-cbc-md5
        fcc-mit-ticketflags = true
[realms]
        $DOMAIN_NAME$.LOCAL = {
                kdc = $adserver$.$domain_name$.local
                admin_server = $adserver$.$domain_name$.local
        }
[domain_realm]
        .$domain_name$.local = $DOMAIN_NAME$.LOCAL
        $domain_name$.local = $DOMAIN_NAME$.LOCAL
[logging]
        default = SYSLOG
```

/etc/samba/smb.conf

```
[global]
    workgroup = $DOMAIN_NAME$
    client signing = auto
    client use spnego = yes
    server max protocol = NT1
    realm=$DOMAIN_NAME$.LOCAL
    security=ADS
    kerberos method = secrets and keytab
    winbind refresh tickets = Yes
    vfs objects = acl_xattr
    map acl inherit = Yes
    store dos attributes = Yes
    winbind use default domain = yes
    idmap config * :            backend = tdb
    idmap config * :            range   = 3000-9999
    idmap config $DOMAIN_NAME$ : backend = rid
    idmap config $DOMAIN_NAME$ : range   = 100000-999999
    template shell = /bin/bash
    template homedir = /home/%U
    map to guest = bad user
    usershare allow guests = no
    log file = /var/log/samba/smbd.log
    log level = 10
    max log size = 500
    load printers = no
    printing = bsd
    printcap name = /dev/null
    disable spoolss = yes
```

I cannot start the winbindd service; when it tries to start as I `apt install` it logs an error that we haven't joined the domain and exits; when I try to start it from the command line systemd says `Failed to start winbindd.service: Unit winbindd.service not found.`

The join, using `net ads join -U administrator`, fails with

```
Failed to join domain: failed to lookup DC info for domain '$DOMAIN_NAME$.LOCAL' over rpc: {Device Timeout} The specified I/O operation on %hs was not completed before the time-out period expired.
```

I can ping $adserver$.$domain_name$.local by name without a problem; I've already done the nonsense with resolv.conf to direct DNS resolution directly to $adserver$.$domain_name$.local by IP rather than letting systemd tell me it's unroutable. I'm wondering about that %hs in the failure message; it looks like it doesn't know what it's trying to connect to, but I don't know where that would be. Updates have been run and are current.

Comment: Is winbind actually installed ? Try turning Avahi off. Does the first nameserver in /etc/resolv.conf point to the DC ? Your other main problem is that the underscore '_' isn't allowed in a dns domain name.

Comment: I'm still stuck with the underscore, allowed or not - once a domain name is set in Windows Server 2003, you cannot change it. The only nameserver in /etc/resolv.conf is the IP of the DC. I'll check on Avahi in the morning - it's 0100 here, far too late to be playing with critical stuff.

Comment: Unless you have a large amount of users, it may just be easier to set up a new domain using a later version of Windows or by using Samba. One problem that you may have is that you will probably still be using the 2K dns zones and these are not compatible with the current AD dns zones.

Comment: "Large amount of users" would be an issue, yes. The current health crisis has cut down the user count, but the raw cost of upgrade makes putting in a new Windows server prohibitively expensive; and the sort of service interruption that would be the result of the sort of ongoing tinkering that we've been doing here precludes putting in a Linux / Samba primary. Meanwhile, though, whether winbind installed is moot, it seems, as it won't run, installed or no, until we join the domain...can we concentrate on one problem at a time please?

Comment: I'll note also that logging in to the domain with `kinit "administrator@$DOMAIN_NAME$.LOCAL"` works just fine... a 'klist' following that shows me an active ticket for that principal on that domain.